# Colab and matplotlib, delate extra infomation

Tags: matplotlib, google-colaboratory

Is there any way to eliminate the extra information that appears when graphing something in Google Colab through Matplotlib? [image of what I want to remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kOv6.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a semicolon after the last line in your cell:

```
plt.hist([predicted, Y_test);
```

This will suppress printing the textual return value of the function, while still showing the chart it creates.